# Streamline a Summary Table by Nesting Categories Using the GT Package

Tags: r

I aim to generate a summary table that organizes data based on two categorical variables. The first variable, `ctry_origin`, serves as a high-level category, while the second, `mfr`, is nested under it. My table counts the occurrences of each `mfr` and groups them by `ctry_origin`. Using the `gt` package, I've been able to add group headers for `ctry_origin`, but the table still redundantly lists this variable in each row. I want to streamline the table by using `ctry_origin` solely as a row header, thereby eliminating repetitive information.

```
library(gt)
library(tidyverse)

gtcars %>%
  dplyr::select(ctry_origin, mfr) %>%
  dplyr::slice(1:8) %>%
  group_by(ctry_origin, mfr) %>%
  summarise(n = n(), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  mutate(row_label = case_when(
    ctry_origin == "Italy" ~ "Italy",
    ctry_origin == "United States" ~ "United States",
    TRUE ~ NA_character_
  )) %>%
  select(-ctry_origin) %>% # This removes the ctry_origin column
  gt(rowname_col = "row_label") %>%
  tab_row_group(
    label = "Italy",
    rows = row_label == "Italy"
  ) %>%
  tab_row_group(
    label = "United States",
    rows = row_label == "United States"
  )
```